# Looking for HTTP proxy server for .NET programming

Tags: .net, proxy

Looking for proxy server functionality as .NET assemblies to reference into my projects.  I want to intercept communications between browser and server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to intercept the communication between a browser and the web server from the client side (browser side) there is a proxy called [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) which is quite nice.

Comment: I see it has programmatic support http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/dev/ Until now I've only used it as a UI. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer based on Fiddler Core http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/Core/